# How to use CME simple binary encoding

Tags: binary-data

Hi I'm looking for an example on how to use the CME Simple Binary Encoding. Is it as simple as generating decoders using the SBETool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is. SBE defines the wire format. SBETool will generate codecs to encode/decode to this format.

There are examples in the github repository:
https://github.com/real-logic/simple-binary-encoding/tree/master/examples

Comment: link is 404. fix please? is the new location https://github.com/real-logic/simple-binary-encoding/tree/master/sbe-samples ? I tried digging in the web archive but this link was never saved.